# Host file not redirecting

Tags: windows-10, redirection, hosts-file

I've been playing around with my Windows 10 host file to get a better understanding of how it works and I've not been successful in redirecting an address yet.

I'm trying to redirect yahoo.com or www.yahoo.com to 216.58.209.36 (www.google.com), im putting:

```
216.58.209.36  yahoo.com
216.58.209.36  www.yahoo.com
```

But when I try loading it in my browser it tells me

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.yahoo.com took too long to respond.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
I've also tried clearing my browsing history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of the `hosts.txt` file.

If all you care about is the TL;DR (too long; didn't read), then scroll down to the bottom of the answer. What follows is an explanation of what's going on, to help you understand *why* you are getting the results you are getting.

`hosts.txt` (typically `/etc/hosts` on Unix-like systems) provides a mapping between a host name and an IP address. The system name resolver is then typically configured to prefer `hosts.txt` entries over DNS, such that `hosts.txt` can be used as a DNS override. This is useful particularly in cases where local names don't exist in DNS, but you simply don't have enough hosts on your network to warrant setting up a local all-out authoritative DNS server with all of what that entails.

However, modern web browsing relies on far more than just the name to IP address mapping.

The typical process goes like something similar to:

1. User enters a URL into the browser's address field, or otherwise triggers a web request
2. Browser looks up the host name from the URL, to an IP address, and connects to that IP address
3. Browser sets up a HTTPS session, if the url is a `https://` URL

- Browser aborts if the certificate presented does not match the host name in the URL

4. Browser tells the remote web server to give it path `/something/whatever` from the host name from the URL
5. Remote web server responds with the requested resource, or typically an error if the request cannot be fulfilled for some reason
6. Browser interprets and displays or acts on the data received from the remote web server

- If the data received is a redirection, then the process starts over on step 1 with that URL instead

By editing `hosts.txt` you change **only** what happens in step 2 above. Web browsing is a lot more complex than just a name lookup!

Also note that web browsers sometimes implement *their own* name lookup functionality, instead of offloading to the resolver provided by the operating system. In such a case, even step 2 won't necessarily get you the result you are after, because it might very well follow the normal name delegation path from the DNS root, so you get the same response as you otherwise would; in that case, `hosts.txt` never gets consulted!

Notably, the browser will still be expecting a certificate for the specific host name in the URL in step 3; and it will tell the remote web server the host name you gave it in step 4.

Since Google's web servers are unlikely to be set up to serve `www.yahoo.com`, whether over HTTP or HTTPS, this fails no later than between step 4 and 5 (the remote web server cannot provide the requested resource).

I have no good explanation for why you are getting a *timeout* rather than a web server error response, but the means of failure is largely up to the remote server, so I suspect it is well within its rights to not respond at all when asked about a host it simply doesn't know about.

And of course, if you are just experimenting, there is no need to use Yahoo or Google. Rather, there are Internet IP addresses and host names [specifically set aside for example and documentation purposes](https://michael.kjorling.se/computers/internet-reservations/examples-and-documentation) which are good for this. For example, you could use `192.0.2.100` for the IP address and `test.example.com` for the host name, as neither of these belongs to anyone in particular. That, or [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918#section-3) space (10.0.0.0 through 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 through 172.31.255.255 or 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255), but you'd still want a corresponding domain name, for which those reserved are good.

## TL;DR:

If you want to see that your `hosts.txt` entry is doing what it should, then open a command prompt and issue the command `ping -n 1 www.yahoo.com` (in your case). It should respond with the IP address you configured. The `-n 1` causes only a single echo request to be sent, because all we are really interested in is the results of the name lookup.

I would prefer `nslookup www.yahoo.com`, but [apparently](https://superuser.com/questions/1211241/host-file-not-redirecting/1211362#comment1767265_1211264) on Windows `nslookup` doesn't look at `hosts.txt` either. (On Linux, it typically does, because it asks the system resolver and the system resolver is normally configured to consult the hosts file; if you want a pure DNS lookup on Linux, you'd typically use `host` or `dig` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Your hosts file is redirecting yahoo.com to 216.58.209.36 as it should. The reason why it is not working as you intended is likely because the web server behind 216.58.209.36 will look for a site named yahoo.com, but since the server is not hosting that site, it will not be found, thus telling you the site cannot be reached.

It is kind of like dialing the wrong number. If you call Alice and ask for Bob, she would probably respond "There's no one here by that name".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything wrong. To prove to yourself that your hosts file entries are having their intended effect, run the following from a Command Prompt:

```
ping www.yahoo.com
```

...and observe that the IP address that gets pinged is the one you specified in your `hosts` file.

As noted in FastEthernet's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1211255/213131) accessing a web server via a hostname not assigned to the server can result in unexpected behavior. However, it's better to use the ping command above to verify the hostname is being mapped to your custom IP address instead of relying on being able to load the site in a browser.

Comment: Not all sites on the Internet respond to ICMP echo requests. Many of the big ones probably do. In this case, there's no reason to use `ping` in the first place; `nslookup` is probably more relevant, since all you are interested in is the IP address mapping for the name.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling `ping` will still show the IP address of the target, whether it responds or not. Also, `nslookup` does not look in the hosts file as it asks the name server directly.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's not necessary for the site to respond to the ping requests for this test to work. And IIRC nslookup by bypasses the hosts file.

Comment: @FastEthernet Of course it's not necessary for the remote host to respond to ICMP echo requests in order to perform a name lookup, but why clog the pipes unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into all sorts of problems with security measures,
since the Google website does not present the right certificate to be seriously
considered as Yahoo.